# RxJS Observables - Call function when any new value emitted

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs

I have following the observable which sucesfully obtains JSON data from a firebase DB:

```
this.http.get('https://testdb.firebaseio.com/.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => {
  // do something with result
});
```

I want to call a function, `foo()`, inside the observable when any *new* value arrives *after* the first pull from the database. To be clear, I want `foo()` only when a value arrives "later".

For instance:

```
this.http.get('https://testdb.firebaseio.com/.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => {

  // Only called when a new value arrives in the stream later, not on the first pull when the stream is first activated.
  foo();

});
```

By later, I mean whenever the subscribed database is updated. I also don't need the actual value that was updated, I just want to trigger a function (which takes no parameters) when any new value arrives.

Comment: What do you mean by new value? The Angular HTTP service observables emit a single response and then complete.

Comment: @cartant My understanding is that an observable, unlike a promise, will emit multiple values over time. For example, as explained here a couple of paragraphs in: https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-manipulate-data-in-ionic-2-part-1/ . `The main difference is that an Observable can emit multiple values over time, whereas a Promise will only emit a value once.`

Comment: "Can" is the operative word in that statement. They have the capability do to that, but they don't have to. And the Angular HTTP service does not; it emits a single response and completes (or errors).

Comment: I see. The Angular/Ionic example that I saw that was updating in realtime was using `FirebaseObjectObservable`, which is probably the difference here (https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-crud-ionic-2-application-with-firebase-angularfire/ ).

Comment: Yep, the AngualrFire2 observables maintain a (WebSocket) connection with the server and listen for changes and will emit new, changed values. (Also, regarding HTTP, the primary difference between observables and promise is that observables are cancellable.)

Comment: As it was said, Http emits a single value. Http benefits from observables because it can retry requests, and requests can be cancelled. If your case differs from Http and you have multiple values, please, update the question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I've no experience with firebase but if you want to [skip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skip.html) the very first value, then `yourObservable.skip(1)` will do it. Where `yourObservable` could be your data source i.e:

```
this.http.get('https://testdb.firebaseio.com/.json')
.map(res => res.json())
.skip(1)
.subscribe((result) => foo();)
```

Comment: Please comment the downvote so that I can improve my answer.